# Loop over json file to get seperate elements in my table

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

i'm working with BootstrapVue. I have a v-for loop which iterates over my json file and put the complete input in my `<tr>`-Tag.

Now I want to have an extra `tr`-Tag for each group in my json files - so I think I need to iterate over these groups first - but I dont know how to do that.

Code in my template:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr> <!-- I WANT TO ITERATE HERE OVER MY GROUPS TO SORT THEM -->
      <div v-for="(item, index) in json" :key="index">
        <b-form-input v-if="item.type" :type="item.type"></b-form-input>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my json:

```
[
    {
        "label": "Input 1",
        "type": "text",
        "group": "Test1"
    },
    {
        "label": "Input 2",
        "type": "text",
        "group": "Test2"
    },
    {
        "label": "Input 3",
        "type": "text",
        "group": "Test3"
    },
    {
        "label": "Input 4",
        "type": "number",
        "group": "Test1"
    }
]
```

This is what the code should look like, just for understanding, if it works:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
       <b-form-input type="text"></b-form-input>
       <b-form-input type="number"></b-form-input>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <b-form-input type="text"></b-form-input>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <b-form-input type="text"></b-form-input>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by extra `<tr`>?

Comment: Can you pls be clear with your sample code on what you are trying to say!

Comment: I'm sorry. Actually it's not extra ```tr```, but for now I only have one ```tr```-Tag and I need every group (Test1, Test2 and Test3) in a seperate ```div``` or ```tr```

Comment: now I'm iterating over all items once - but I need to check the groups first and place them after knowing my group in a seperate div  / tr based on this group

Comment: try the below solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting v-for for `tr`

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(group, key) in getComputedJson" :key="key">
      <div v-for="(item, indexer) in group" :key="indexer">
        <b-form-input v-if="item.type" :type="item.type"></b-form-input>
     </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and define a computed handler like

```
<script>
export default {
 computed: {
  getComputedJson() {
   const computedJson = {};
   this.json.forEach(item => {
    if(!computedJson[item.group]) {
     computedJson[item.group] = [];
     computedJson[item.group].push({label: item.label, type: item.type});
    } else {
    computedJson[item.group].push({label: item.label, type: item.type});
   }
  }
return computedJson;
}
</script>
```

Comment: this can't work out, because first i need to loop over my groups and then place all other inputs which have the same group in seperate divs..

Comment: oh I get it wait let me update the solution

Comment: check the updated answer now

Comment: thanks ! - is it also possible to push options for checkboxes or selection?

Comment: yes but you got to handle them using v-if on the template end

Comment: hi, thanks. I've tried.. to input also some ```b-form-select```, ```b-form-checkbox-group``` and a ```b-form-datepicker``` - but I don't know how to solve that, I've tried with a ```v-if``` but actually it does not work out for me

Comment: Create a separate qsn explaining your problem

Comment: And tag it here

Comment: Lets carry it forward over there

Comment: Seperate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467729/display-selection-chekboxes-datepicker-dynamically-based-on-json-file